# Display all posts under child sub category in sidebar on post page?

Tags: posts, categories, sidebar

I am trying to make a custom sidebar for my posts in certain categories. It will look something like this.

[image]

My category structure looks like this:

- Parent 1

  - Child 1

    - Sub Child 1
    - Sub Child 2
  - Child 1

    - Sub Child 1
    - Sub Child 2
- Parent 2

What I want to do is to display all posts under Sub Child 1 and 2. I will be more specific, lets say we have 3 posts, 2 of them is under sub child 1 and last one is under sub child 2.  Then I only want the 2 posts that is under sub child 1 to be displayed under Sub child 1, and the 3 :rd post to display only under sub child 2.

I have been looking in 2 days now over the Internet to figure this out how to do this, but I dont get what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code and what I am trying to modify:

```
<?php 
$cat = get_the_category();
$catID = get_cat_ID($cat);
$subcats = get_categories('child_of=' . $catID);
    foreach($subcats as $subcat) {
    echo '<h3>';
    echo '<a href="' . get_category_link($subcat->cat_ID) . '">';
    echo '/' . $subcat->cat_name . '';
    echo '</a></h3>';
    echo '<ul>';
    $subcat_posts = get_posts('cat=' . $subcat->cat_ID);
    foreach($subcat_posts as $subcat_post) {
        $postID = $subcat_post->ID;
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($postID) . '">';
    echo get_the_title($postID);
    echo '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} 
?>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you could take a big step using [`wp_list_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/wp_list_categories) with a `walker` to add a additional Unordered List to every item.

**The code**:

```
$cat_id = get_query_var( 'cat' );
$subcats = get_categories( 'child_of=' . $cat_id ); // child categories

class Cat_Walker extends Walker_Category {
    function end_el( &$output, $page, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $posts = get_posts( 'cat=' . $page->term_id );

        if ( sizeof( $posts ) > 0 ) {
            $output .= '<ul>';

            foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
                $output .= sprintf( '<li><a href="%1$s">%2$s</a></li>', get_permalink( $post->ID ), $post->post_title );
            }

            $output .= '</ul>';
        }

        $output .= '</li>';
    }
}

foreach ( $subcats as $subcat ) {
    $subsubcats = get_categories( 'child_of=' . $subcat->term_id ); // sub child categories

    foreach ( $subsubcats as $subsubcat ) {
        $args = array(
            'title_li'         => '',
            'show_option_none' => '',
            'taxonomy'         => 'category',
            'child_of'         => $subsubcat->term_id,
            'walker'           => new Cat_Walker( )
        );

        wp_list_categories( $args );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I would call myself a noob on php, but how does the walker work? What do I have to pass with args to make it work?

Comment: I added some arguments to `$args` for you, this will give you a clean Unordered List wich you can style with CSS to get the look you want. For more arguments, see [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/wp_list_categories) page in the Codex.

Comment: It shows parent categorys, and for each category it displays the post under it, how do i exclude the parent and child. So that I only have Sub Child category. And it also displays every single category on the site. How do I display all sub cateogries in Child 1, 2 or 3? Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I altered the code a little, now you will have an Unordered List for every sub child category with their posts.

Comment: How do I make it show only all the sub categories that are under parent category (Child 1), now it shows all of sub categories. It will show All Sub categories only under child 1, becuse the post is under child 1. So then you can easy go to another sub category if you like. Thanks for reply, this means alot!

Comment: I don't know exactly if there is an extra question in your last comment, do you want to know how to always show items under Child 1? - `$cat_id` is containing the parent category. is your question answered? In that case please vote up and accept my answer? :)

Comment: Sorry for bother you so much! Well now it displays all child sub categories and the related posts to them. I only want to display all the sub categories under the parent category. So if I have G - Gaming - Gaming Season 3, so the third is what we display now. Gaming Season 3, and i want to display all sub categories under gaming and the posts under them, so if I make Gaming Season 2 It should be in the sidebar. So how will I do this ? Thank you so much i will vote up for sure!

Comment: All questions are welcome here ;) comment out the line of `$subsubcats` and the `foreach` line. This will show the child sub pages.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after searching all day .. collecting & combine the code.. this is it :

```
<?php $categories =  get_categories('child_of='.get_queried_object()->term_id); if(!empty($categories)):  
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $category_id = $category->term_id;
        query_posts('cat='.$category_id."&order=ASC");
        if ( have_posts() ) :
           ?>        <h3><?php echo $category->name; ?><span></span></h3><?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?><ul><li><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li></ul><?php endwhile;?><?php endif; 
    } endif; ?>
```

enjoy it :)

Answer (score 0):

Function for getting all categories and their post for a particular parent category

```
function get_cat_subcat_posts($catid){
            $categories =  get_categories('child_of='.$catid);

            if(!empty($categories)):  

                foreach ($categories as $category) {

                $category_id = $category->term_id;

                query_posts('cat='.$category_id."&order=ASC");
                if ( have_posts() ) :
            ?>

                 <div class="detail_row">
                 <h3><?php echo $category->name; ?><span></span></h3>
                    <ul>
                <?php 

                // Start the Loop.
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();            
                ?>

                      <li><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

                     <?php
                        endwhile;

                    ?>
                 </ul>
                  </div>

            <?php
                endif; 
                wp_reset_query();

                // Recall the category posts function
                get_cat_subcat_posts($category_id);

                }

            endif;

            }
```

Comment: This function can display multilevel category and their posts thanks. copy this from function get_cat_subcat_posts($catid){

Comment: Call the Function like $catid = get_cat_ID('Bible Studies'); get_cat_subcat_posts($catid);

Comment: Please: Additional infos as [edit]s to your answer.